# MVC 4 Controller action parameter System.FormatException bug

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

We are finding that an ajax controller action which backs a KendoUI grid is throwing a lot of `System.FormatException` exceptions, see below.

The exceptions are being thrown by the MVC stack, when attempting to bind the query string parameters from the AJAX request to the action parameters - long before the action code is ever executed. However they are not being thrown on EVERY request, the same POST data will sometimes cause an exception and sometimes not.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32' failed. See the inner exception for more information. ---> System.Exception: NaN is not a valid value for Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequestModelBinder.TryGetValue[T](ModelBindingContext bindingContext, String key, T& result)
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequestModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

The action takes a set of parameters, some optional, for a DB query, and returns the resultset as JSON. It looks like this:

```
public ActionResult List([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? companyID, int? statusID, int? countryID, int? licenseID, string userID, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

and the AJAX post values look like this:

```
    sort=&page=1&group=&filter=&companyID=&licenseID=&countryID=&statusID=&userID=&fromDate=24%2F12%2F2012&toDate=23%2F01%2F2013
```

The values of each parameter are taken from a set of drop downs on the page. The exceptions are happening only when the "all" option is set in one of these dropdowns, where there is no value set.

```
<select name="CompanyID"><option value="">All Companies</option>
    <option value="1">Comapny 1</option>
    <option value="2">Company 2</option>
</select>
<!-- ... snip ... -->
```

The confusing thing is that none of the parameters in question is of type `int`, they are all `int?`, `string` or `DateTime` or `DataSourceRequest`.

The exception is being raised by the code in `System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType`, and it looks from the stack trace like it's getting the type of the parameter wrong.

My reading has suggested that in the case where the value of a parameter is `null` or `String.Empty`, then it should pass a `null` onto the controller action. This seems confirmed by the source I found [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ValueProviderResult.cs) (line 54):

```
// if this is a user-input value but the user didn't type anything, return no value
string valueAsString = value as string;
if (valueAsString != null && valueAsString.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

I have found reference to an old MVC-3 bug which caused incorrect caching of internal information and caused this exception. There's a discussion of it [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1632006/4206895.aspx) where it was confirmed as a MVC3 RC2 bug, so I can't imagine it would still be this issue, but might there be something related? The suggested fix was to add the following to `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

At @mattytommo's suggestion, we have tried rearranging the signature such that the nullable parameters all come last, but this makes no difference.

Comment: You should **really** consider posting a model of some sort, that action method signature is *awful*. How are you getting away with putting non-optional parameters **after** optional parameters?

Comment: @mattytommo Yes, something we should probably look into, but it was one area that was put together quickly so not had time to fiddle with the Kendo setup code which generates the AJAX call etc. I had read of possible problems with non nullable parameters after nullable ones, but I've not seen a case where they are not passed through, or when they error.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the optional arguments which we added, it is down to the KendoUI script.

The Kendo javascript adds a bunch of parameters (group, sort, page) which get mapped onto the `DataSourceRequest` object.

The `Page` Property of this object is defined as

```
public int Page { get; set; }`
```

But in the case where the filter we are applying returns *no results* (an empty grid) the javascript is setting `page=NaN`, hence the error:

```
System.Exception: NaN is not a valid value for Int32
```